# unit test unsubscribe on fromEvent(this.document, 'click')

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, domdocument, removeeventlistener

I want to make sure that after receiving the click it is waiting for, it unsubscribes:

```
const documentListener = fromEvent(this.document, 'click').subscribe(e => {
  // do some thing
  documentListener.unsubscribe();
});
```

I am mocking the document which is injected (`@Inject(DOCUMENT) public document: Document`) and did put spys on addEventListener and removeEventListener.

Tis is my Mock:

```
class MockDocument {   
    private listeners = [];

    createEvent(name: string) {
        if (this.listeners.some(l => l.name === name)) {
            this.listeners.find(l => l.name === name).f.call(new Event(name));
        }
    }
    addEventListener(name: string, f: any) {
        this.listeners.push({name: name, f: f});
    }
    removeEventListener(name: string, f: any) {
        this.listeners.splice(
            this.listeners.indexOf(l => l.name === name), 1);
    }
}
```

I thought `fromEvent(this.document, 'click')` would call `addEventListener` but aparently it doesn't.

I thought `unsubscribe()` would call `removeEventListener` on `document` but it aparently doesn't.

I added all DOMDocument methods to my mock (`get activeElement()`, `adoptNode()` ..) but none are ver called after `unsubscribe()`.

How can i test that the unsubscribe is called?
How can i mock the subscribe Part?